# How to determine if a location is inside a UIbeizerPath?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

How do I go about determining if a certain point lies in the beizer path or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if([beizerPath containsPoint:point])
{
    NSLog("point lies in Path");
}
```

use this . hope it helps u.

Comment: Couldn't have been simpler! Thank you.